# Migrating from cfs:gridfs to cfs:s3

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, data-migration, collectionfs

In a meteor project I maintain there has been cause to look at moving away from `gridfs` as the backend to `CollectionFS` and moving towards `s3`.

One thing I would be keen to do is migrate images / files currently stored using the `gridfs` collections.

Has anyone attempted this before? I can't find any guides or even suggestions.

My thinking right now is along the lines of;

1. Create a new collection backed by s3
2. Iterate over old collection pushing the data into s3
3. Update code to point to new collection

Does this seem sound?

Comment: Seems sound! I started with CollectionFS on S3 but eventually moved to slingshot to reduce server load for large file transfers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did this!

You're basically right, here's how I did it. Migration is a pretty easy process.  I've gone from GridFS to S3.

1) By adding  `new FS.Store.S3("store_name",{})`, CollectionFS automatically clones the meta data of existing files in the old store for your new store. But, all file sizes are zero in this new store.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.S3("s3images", {}),
        new FS.Store.GridFS("images", {})
    ]
});
```

2) While you have both stores in place, you need to manually migrate the content using the piping as referenced here https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/How-to:-Convert-a-file-already-stored.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
Images.find().forEach(function (fileObj) {
var readStream = fileObj.createReadStream('images');
var writeStream = fileObj.createWriteStream('s3images');
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
});
}
```

Hopefully after this you will now see your new store's file sizes matches the old one!

3) Optionally, remove the old store.  If you keep both, inserted files are added to both, with priority given to the first store in the array.

Reference: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/747